# RShiny - select plot

Tags: r, shiny

I have 4 plots and want to only show one plot at a time as selected by the user. I don't want 4 separate tabs. Any example code much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Please provide more details as to your specific problem and what you've tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `toggle` in `shinysj` package to show / hide plots:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(), #Necessary to activate shinyjs
    selectInput("select", "Select plot:", 1:4),
    plotOutput("p1"),
    plotOutput("p2"),
    plotOutput("p3"),
    plotOutput("p4")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$p1 <- renderPlot({ plot(iris) })
    output$p2 <- renderPlot({ plot(mtcars) })
    output$p3 <- renderPlot({ plot(0) })
    output$p4 <- renderPlot({ plot(1) })
    
    observeEvent(input$select, {
      req(input$select)
      shinyjs::toggle("p1", condition = input$select == 1)
      shinyjs::toggle("p2", condition = input$select == 2)
      shinyjs::toggle("p3", condition = input$select == 3)
      shinyjs::toggle("p4", condition = input$select == 4)
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks - this works great.